# GraphQL Query where two datasets share common list items

Tags: graphql

I have a GraphQL query that looks like this:

```
query ($device_id: ID!) {
  device(id: $device_id) {
    hostname: name
    tags {
      name
    }
  }
  vlans {
    name
    tags {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

Instead of dumping all vlans along with the device, I would like to only return vlans where the vlan tags share a common tag with the device tags. Any way to achieve this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not something you can do within the query. You can either have a specific endpoint for the intersection, or manually filter the results in the client

Answer (score 0):

You're running two queries at the same time. These will run independently but can share query variables.

I suggest creating a second `vlans` query as:

```
query vlansByDevice(id: ID!): [vlan]
```

Which looks at the `id` variable to find the appropriate vlans based on common tags.

Then you could do:

```
query ($device_id: ID!) {
  device(id: $device_id) {
    hostname: name
    tags {
      name
    }
  }
  vlansByDevice(id: $device_id) {
    name
    tags {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, sounds like this might be what I'm looking for if I can figure it out :D (I'm a GraphQL noob). Until then I'm just filtering it on the client which in this case is a jinja template, so I'm doing: {% for vlan in vlans if vlan['tags'] | intersect(device['tags']) %}